# how to pass data between forms without buttons, c#

Tags: c#, winforms, pass-data

I have a log in form, in which the admin first log in and add some passwords and save them in an array of string, then the users should be able to log in with those passwords, but I want to know how can I have access to those arrays in my log in form? actually how to pass data back to the first form (log in form) without any buttons for this?
I use to make an object and pass the array to log in page's constructor but it didn't help.
tanx

Comment: Is this a school assignment? Otherwise this design already sounds flawed.

Comment: no it's not an assignment, and yes, how should I get and set a form into another form? I have no idea how to do that, that's one of the ways. (I've use the constructor to set the arrays in log in page, and call it from last page), I don't know, I'm confused about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use public [Properties.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)

Comment: you can't access them in another form.

Comment: What do you mean?  They have public access modifiers.

Comment: He, probably, means - without an instance of a class that defines these properties.